# Eclipse console is terminated on maven build

Tags: eclipse, maven

I intend to run a simple Spring MVC application using Maven. When I try to perform `maven clean / build`, nothing runs on console instead it shows message as

> " Projectname [maven build] ..[JDK path]/javaw.exe"

I have set valid JDK path in system env variables and in the `eclipse.ini` file. Please help as I can't find anything related to this problem on Google.

Please refer to the attached image for the error:

[image]

Comment: Does your build work on plain command line ?

Comment: Yes, it works with command line

Comment: You should the configuration for your runtime environment in Eclipse..